# String Manipulation in masm32 assembly

Tags: string, assembly, masm, messagebox, masm32

I have a problem in coding in assembly in masm32. I'm trying to manipulate a string based on the value of the variables during the process. Here is the code I've been working on.

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
  mTitle db "My reminder",0
  mCaption db "Today is %S!! Good %S! Are you doing fine today?",dData.wDayOfWeek, day,0
  day db 1024 dup(?)
  dData SYSTEMTIME <>

.code
GetTimeData proc

  push offset dData
  call GetSystemTime

  ret

GetTimeData endp
ShowMessage proc

  push MB_YESNO
  push offset mTitle
  push offset mCaption
  push NULL
  call MessageBox

  ret

ShowMessage endp
IdentifyChoice proc

  ret

IdentifyChoice endp
start:
  call GetTimeData
  call ShowMessage
  call IdentifyChoice

  push 0
  call ExitProcess
end start
```

I'm trying to put the variables inside a string an print them out in a Message Box. I don't quite know what to do in my string. Help, guys.

Comment: Well, you can't do that until you've got the values of all of those variables. `dData` is filled out when you call `GetSystemTime`, and `day` doesn't seem to be filled out anywhere. Once you have all the values, call `wsprintf`, and then pass its output to `MessageBox`.

Comment: Outputting values instead of placeholders like `%S` is not common functionality of OS calls (like `MessageBox`), but in C/C++ the `printf` family of functions does that. For `sprintf/wsprintf` you have to provide it with big enough buffer for the output string, where the placeholders are replaced by values. Using that `dData.wDayOfWeek` during compile time in `db` is meaningless, unless you wanted memory address of it (value is not known yet). It may be an argument for printf in runtime. Also make sure you use ascii/wide strings correctly, depending on which part of win/clib api you call.

Comment: I'm having another problem guys. I can't seem to output the data in my SYSTEMTIME using stdout function.

Comment: The `StdOut` function prints zero-terminated strings and nothing else. If you want to print a number using `StdOut` you'll have to convert it to a string first (e.g. using `wsprintf`). Or you could do it in a single step using e.g. `crt_printf`. Go through the examples that came with masm32.

Comment: In assembly you should think more low-level, about stream of byte values rather, than numbers or strings... If you have somewhere stored a number, it usually requires some effort to output it in desired form, i.e. as decimal string. If you will start to use clib extensively, you can do lot of stuff in similar way like in C/C++ (do you know C?), but if you want to stay inside OS calls only, not linking to clib, prepare for lot of work to do just to output any non-compile-time-prepared-for-output value. Static strings are easy, others require your own code to format the value into string.